# VBOs Extremely slow on real hardware (LG Optimus V 670) - Android 2.2.1

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

I'm working on a 2d OpenGL graphics engine for my android game, so far I have implemented basic non textured quad rendering via VBOs.

To do this my graphics engine creates a VBO of a quad when initialized and upon rendering 
draws it using location/dimensions specified by a Polygon2D object.

When rendering 30 - 50 quads on actual hardware (LG Optimus V 670) the frame rate is around 5 - 10 and on the emulator it is 30 - 40.

Here's the code to give a better understanding

```
public void CreateBuffers(GL10 gl)
{
    GL11 gl11 = (GL11)gl;

    mQuadBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(QUAD2D.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();

    mQuadBuffer.put(QUAD2D, 0, QUAD2D.length);


    mQuadBuffer.flip();

    int[] buffer = new int[1];

    gl11.glGenBuffers(1, buffer, 0);
    mQuadVBOId = buffer[0];

    gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mQuadVBOId);
    gl11.glBufferData(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mQuadBuffer.capacity() * 4, mQuadBuffer, GL11.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}



public void draw(GL10 gl) {

    GL11 gl11 = (GL11)gl;

    Polygon2D poly;
    int length = mPolygons.size();

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mQuadVBOId);
    gl11.glVertexPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {

        poly = mPolygons.get(i);

        gl11.glPushMatrix();

        gl11.glTranslatef(poly.x, poly.y, 0);
        gl11.glScalef(poly.width, poly.height, 0);

        gl11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);

        gl11.glPopMatrix(); 

    }

    gl11.glBindBuffer(GL11.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

}
```

Am I doing something wrong, other OpenGl applications seem to run fine such as Replica Island.

I doubt this is useful but here are the specs http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=2746&c=lg_vm670_optimus_v

Answer (score 0):

The VBO's are not slow, but the many separate draw calls are. You should combine all of the quads in one VBO (i.e. calculate the vertex positions for each quad) and draw it with one call. To be able to do that, you will also have to change from using `GL_LINE_LOOP` to `GL_LINES` to get separation between the quads.